# Get Generic list using Hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, generics

I have two classes State and City and two separate **DAO** objects to perform **CRUD** operation on *State* and *City*.

```
List<Chapter> getAllStates();
int save(State state);
```

and

```
List<City> getAllCities();
int save(Citycity);
```

I can have many more classes which need to have their own DAOs.

I want to use generic so that I will have only one **DAO** object which can perform **CRUD** on any given type.

I am trying.

```
@Override
    public <T> List<T> getAllItems() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria<T>().list();
    }
```

gives the following error:

> Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token"

and

```
@Override
    public <T> List<T> getAllItems() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(T).list();
    }
```

which shows

> T cannot be resolved to a variable

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

If yes please help me with example or correcting my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple solutions to your problem.  Using your example, the easiest would be to simply pass the class type as a method argument:

```
public <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> clazz) {
   return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz).list();
}
```

But if you're looking for a slightly more elegant way, it would require the involvement of a generic-based class and interface to achieve this:

```
public interface GenericDAO<T> {
    List<T> findAll();
}

public class GenericDAOImpl<T> implements GenericDAO<T> {
    private final Class<T> entityClass;
    /* others stuff */

    public GenericDAOImpl() {
      ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
      this.entityClass = (Class<T>)type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
       return sessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass).list();
    }
}
```

The above allows you to infer the type argument from the interface stub and then use that captured type in methods inside the implementation class.

Comment: Thanks Naros, I used first approach which served my purpose.